# Delete one month older files but keep last date files of last two month

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to keep the backup file started on 31st april and ended next day.

how to get last day backup files .
backup file names are identical except the timestamp and it starts like 221information_schema202205052355

```
import os
import time
import datetime

def main():
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-03-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
    to_delete = 'D:\S135'

    if os.path.exists(to_delete):
        if os.path.isdir(to_delete):
            for root_folder, folders, files in os.walk(to_delete):
                for file in files:
                    curpath = os.path.join(to_delete, file)
                    file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
                    if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(days=14):   
                        if file_modified > start_date :
                            print(curpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # invoking main function
    main()
```

Comment: April has 30 days and not 31 days. So you need to keep files start only with 221information_schema20220430 and 221information_schema20220501 ? How about the other files ? you need to delete it ?

Comment: Yes, delete all files except last date of last two months